# How do I group 2 columns to only get the latest version of the unique row?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Table structure]

Above is a piece of the output, I'm trying to get only the latest combination of FID and SID. i.e. FID: 1, SID: 1

This is my current SQL

```
 SELECT * FROM sensors, Location_polygon s_lp WHERE username = '$username'
 ORDER BY Datetime DESC;
```

Grouping by FID and SID is having the unexpected result of just showing all rows where FID = 1 and SID = 1.

Anyone have any idea?

My expected result:

[image: Expected Results]

The current table structure with example data is: 
'sensors' table

- [FID] => 9
- [SID] => 1
- [Datetime] => 2015-05-04 00:00:00
- [Sensor1] => 1000
- [Sensor2] => 100
- [Sensor3] => 100
- [Battery] => 10

'Location_polygon' table

- [username] => judy
- [FID] => 1
- [SID] => 1
- [lat1] => 31.446376
- [long1] => -83.597959
- [lat2] => 31.443103
- [long2] => -83.598051
- [lat3] => 31.442641
- [long3] => -83.594875
- [lat4] => 31.44486
- [long4] => -83.594595
- [lat5] => 31.446385
- [long5] => -83.596625
- [type] => SAND

Comment: No JOIN condition? What's the table definitions for sensors and Location_polygon?

Comment: WHat is your expected result , add them into the question from the sample data.

Comment: Please add your table definition and sample data

Comment: I added my expected results, I don't have access to the explicit data structure but I can show the columns and sample data. I'll add that in a bit.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: I didn't set up the database nor do I have access to it as of yet but my intention is to make FID, SID and Time Taken a composite key.

Comment: Abhik's solution assumes that intent, but the data doesn't presently support that objective.

Comment: I added the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the best way to complete this task, but you can try it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sensors s
JOIN Location_polygon s_lp 
    ON s.FID = s_lp.FID and s.SID = s_lp.SID
WHERE username = '$username' and Datetime = (
    SELECT max(Datetime) FROM sensors)
```

My point is: if you want to select only last combinations, you need to get last date. This could be done by a subquery. Also we can use INNER JOIN by FID and SID like @Abhik Chakraborty above that eliminates Cartesian and repetitions.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do and I tried it myself but it's giving me the following warning however. 

<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: @Jebzaki add some changes to the answer. INNER JOIN from Abhik Chakraborty answer can remove repetitions if (FID, SID) couple is unique.

Comment: Your edited code did work as expect it gave me the combinations of 1,3 and 1,1 but strangely not 1,2 but thank you very much this is a great starting point to a final solution for me.

Comment: @Jebzaki that could be if you haven't appropriate FID and SID in one of the tables. Try the same query but change JOIN type to the LEFT (RIGHT if you missed FID, SID in sensors table)

Comment: FID 1 with SID 2 is within the sensors table


- [FID] => 1
- [SID] => 2
- [Datetime] => 2015-05-09 19:51:58
- [Sensor1] => 1100
- [Sensor2] => 100
- [Sensor3] => 100
- [Battery] => 0



The only real difference is it's Datetime value which is less than both FID=1 SID=1 and FID=1 SID=3

Left and right join gave both the same results by the way.

Comment: Should be something like this 

SELECT * FROM sensors s JOIN Location_polygon lp ON s.FID = lp.FID and s.SID = lp.SID WHERE username = '$username' and Datetime = ( SELECT FID, SID, max(Datetime) FROM sensors s2 WHERE s.FID = s2.FID AND s.SID = s2.SID)

Where it only gets the max Datetime for each combination of FIDs and their respective SIDs.

Comment: Word can not express how grateful I am hr6134.

My final query

SELECT * FROM sensors s JOIN Location_polygon lp ON s.FID = lp.FID and s.SID = lp.SID WHERE username = '$username' and Datetime = ( SELECT max(Datetime) FROM sensors s2 WHERE s.FID = s2.FID AND s.SID = s2.SID) ORDER BY Datetime DESC;

Giving me [these results](http://i.imgur.com/dXLRaKZ.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You may get the desired set using

```
select s_lp.* from Location_polygon s_lp
join(
 select fid,sid,max(time_taken) as time_taken from Location_polygon
 group by fid,sid
)x
on x.fid = s_lp.fid and x.sid=s_lp.sid and x.time_taken = s_lp.time_taken
```

If you have some additional where condition add them at the end with respect to the first alias `s_lp` something as `where s_lp.col_name = {some condition}`

UPDATE: From the comment it appears to have 2 tables and date is in different table, so the query would be

```
select s_lp.* from sensors s
join(
 select fid,sid,max(Datetime) as Datetime from sensors
 group by fid,sid
)x
on x.fid = s.fid and x.sid=s.sid and x.Datetime = s.Datetime
join Location_polygon s_lp on s_lp.fid = s.fid and s_lp.sid = s.sid
WHERE s_lp.username = '$username'
```

Comment: I added the table structure above, that should help a bit

Comment: A small correction in your update "select s.* sensors s ..."

This also works, thank you for your time.